# round a select, to more decimal values

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have this query:

```
SELECT  
POWER( (1 + ( 1.00 ) * (VL_TAXA/100.0) ), ( QT_PRAZODIASU / 252.00000000000 ) ),
POWER( (1 + (( VL_PERCENT_INDEX / 100.0) * (VL_TAXA/100.0)) ), ( -QT_PRAZODIASU / 252.000000000000 ) ),
POWER( (1 + ( VL_PERCENT_INDEX / 100.0) * (VL_TAXA/100.0) ), ( QT_PRAZODIASU / 252.000000000000 ) ),
((    VL_MTM * (
       CASE RISCO_JUROS
         WHEN 'S' THEN POWER( (1 + ( 1.00 ) * (VL_TAXA/100.0) ), ( QT_PRAZODIASU / 252.00000000000 ) )
       ELSE 1.0
       END )
       /
       (
       CASE ID_FRISK
         WHEN 'RELA3' THEN POWER( (1 + ( 1.00 ) * (TAXA_MOEDA3/100.0) ), ( QT_PRAZODIASU / 252.00000000000 ) )
       ELSE 1.0
       END )
       )
       - VL_PRINCIPAL * (      
       CASE ID_MODULO_CALCULO
         WHEN 11 THEN ( 1 + ( TAXA_FWD2 * QT_PRAZODIASC ) / 36000.000000000000 ) / ( 1 + ( TAXA_FWD1 * DC_INI_FWD ) / 36000.000000000000 ) - 1
       ELSE 0.0
       END ) 
 )
       *       
 (
       CASE ID_MODULO_CALCULO
         WHEN 10 THEN POWER( (1 + ( VL_PERCENT_INDEX / 100.0) * (VL_TAXA/100.0) ), ( -QT_PRAZODIASU / 252.000000000000 ) )
       ELSE 1.0
       END 
 ) 

 FROM My_Table WHERE ID_TRANSACAO = '181872'
```

The result I get is this:

```
| 1.00501081469 | 0.995014168 | 1.005010815 | -151372478.940930 |   |
| 1.00501081469 | 0.995014168 | 1.005010815 | -151372478.940930 |   |
| 1.00501081469 | 0.995014168 | 1.005010815 | -151372478.940930 |   |
```

How can I make the second column ('0.995014168') To have more decimals?

I'm trying to convert to `decimal`, even using `round` with no success.

Comment: I made it with `cast(POWER( (1 + (( VL_PERCENT_INDEX / 100.0) * (VL_TAXA/100.0)) ), ( -QT_PRAZODIASU / 252.000000000000 ) )as decimal(19,17)),`. is this something useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at MS Docs about [POWER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql) function:

> **Return Types**
>   Returns the same type as submitted in float_expression. For example, if a decimal(2,0) is submitted as float_expression, the result returned is decimal(2,0).

CAST left operand as DECIMAL(18, NumDecimals)

> ```
> -- without CAST
>
> SELECT POWER(1 + (52/100.0) * 0.23, 0.268);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 1.03073935       |
> ```

> ```
> -- CAST as DECIMAL(18,12)
>
> SELECT POWER(CAST(1 + (52/100.0) * 0.23 AS DECIMAL(18,12)), 0.268);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 1.030739345889   |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e37b610d279a9963b6a47d45130245d0)*